# How to use ConversationBot from @microosft/teamsfx and EventHandler from botbuiler in the microsoft team app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am developing an app using teamsfx toolkit and I have two important use case.

Need to send notifications to particular users via API
I also need to send a welcome message to newly installed users.
I am using ConversationBot from @microosft/temasfx library to set adapter config and send notifications to users using API/notification URL like

```
const bot = new ConversationBot({
  // The bot id and password to create BotFrameworkAdapter.
  adapterConfig: {
    appId: config.botId,
    appPassword: config.botPassword,
  }}
 // and when the server.post api use this to send notification
 for (const target of await Mybot.notification.installations()) {
```

I also need to extend an EventHandler class to override

```
this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {()
```

method to send a welcome message. But I am unable to like these two classes in the same app.

I have

```
const bot = new ConversationBot
```

Like I also have

```
class WelcomeBot extends ActivityHandler
{
this.onMemebersAdded(){//sending welcome message}
```

So the question is how to link both in the same bot app so that I can send a welcome Message using EventHandler and send Notifications via ConversationBot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is created via Teams Toolkit, probably you have following code (normally in `index.js|ts`):

```js
server.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
  await bot.requestHandler(req, res);
});
```

Here `bot` is a `ConversationBot`. To integrate your `WelcomeBot` with `ConversationBot`, please change the code `await bot.requestHandler(req, res);` to `await bot.adapter.processActivity(req, res, (context) => welcomeBot.run(context));`

The full code may look like:

```js
/// init somewhere
const bot = new ConversationBot...
const welcomeBot = new WelcomeBot...

/// The "/api/messages" handler
server.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
  await bot.adapter.processActivity(req, res, (context) => welcomeBot.run(context));
});
```

The details behind are - All bot operations depend on `Adapter`. The `ConversationBot` provides a helper method `requestHandler` to simplify the code. But if you'd like to add your own bot logic to the `Adapter`, you need to explicitly get `Adapter` via `ConversationBot.adapter`, then add your own logic.