# teams toolkit app notification bot welcome message

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, message, adaptive-cards, teams-toolkit

I am using teams toolkit version 4 and I created an app with two tabs. One is a notification bot configured with restify and other one is tab. The notification bot did install with adaptive cards as I wanted adaptive cards only. This is not a problem. But,I cannot quite find a way to fire the first welcome adaptive card in the notification bot automatically.

This is my botActivityHandler.js file

[image]

For development , I used the Invoke web request API and issued from my powershell to see the first welcome adaptive card.

This is the index.js file

[image]

Finally this is the init file

[image]

Any suggestions how can a display the the welcome card everytime user switches tabs and selects the notificiation bot tab

This is the folder structure for my bot

[image]

I tried reading documentation but it is not give a clear pointer to how to achieve this and I cannot find anything about this on the internet at any other source either. Every solution I see is using powershell parallely to manually send requests to see the adaptive card. I want this for the user to happen but not manually. So, they do not have to have a command line and powershell to execute rest api request.

Here is the app running in teams with two tabs.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bot Framework SDK supports [welcome message](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?tabs=javascript) that you may need to implement your own `TeamsActivityHandler` and its `onMembersAdded` method.

If your app is created via Teams Toolkit, probably you already have following code:

```js
/// initialize.ts
const bot = new ConversationBot...

/// index.ts
server.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
  await bot.requestHandler(req, res);
});
```

To add welcome message, you may need to add your own `TeamsActivityHandler`:

```js
/// myBot.ts
class MyBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.onMembersAdded = ...
  }
}
```

Then, use it to handle bot event:

```js
/// init somewhere
const bot = new ConversationBot...
const myBot = new MyBot...

/// The "/api/messages" handler
server.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
  await bot.requestHandler(req, res, async (context) => {
    await myBot.run(context);
  });
});
```

You can find more welcome message samples from the [Bot Framework SDK document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?tabs=javascript).

And there's also another question about [adding welcome message to notification bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152178/how-to-use-conversationbot-from-microosft-teamsfx-and-eventhandler-from-botbuil/).

============= Update ==============

The `BotActivityHandler` implementation looks right, but it seems something wrong in `index.js`:

- please try `bot.adapter.process(req, res, ...` instead of `bot.adapter.processActivity(req, res, ...`?
- if still not work, please log `req.body` and `context.activiy.text` to see if received message is correct

```js
server.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
  /// log req.body ...
  bot.adapter.process(req, res, async(context) => {
    /// log context.activity.text ...
    await botActivityHandler.run(context);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is it also possible to just initiate or trigger a http post dynamically at run time at app or tab load with azure functions.?? I mean there must be some function that runs at loading or after install something... I just cannot find it .. Actually I am not using SDK but teams toolkit( I think this is different from SDK,  it is azure functions)

Comment: Do you mean that your tab is hosted by azure functions? And would like the action to be triggered by some user first loading that tab?

Comment: AFAIK, teams tab depends on teams-js client SDK which only works on frontend but not backend. So the workaround may be - get tab context via `microsoftTeams.app.getContext()`, then send user info `context.user` to your backend azure function to see if it's the first time that user opens your tab (may need certain storage to store all existing users).

Comment: Yes "Do you mean that your tab is hosted by azure functions? And would like the action to be triggered by some user first loading that tab? " is correct

Comment: From tab you can get user info via teams-js client SDK `microsoftTeams.app.getContext()`. Perhaps you can have some connections between your frontend and backend, to use that user info to trigger something.

Comment: Hey I figured that the SDK will also work with the toolkit setup and so I went with the first way you descibed that is using the TeamsActivityHandler. The code did compile and run. I just do not see any text message or card automatically (without invoking web request from command line). I fire the "Hello" text message or any other text message on local debug session, but there is no reply. I added the screesnhots of my code in the original post above . Please see those images and comment if you can figure out the problem. My goal is to deploy on azure for dev and then publish to teams.

Comment: Updated the answer as well - it seems something wrong in `index.js`

Comment: Yes that works now but I see two message all at once instead of just one. I tried commenting the server.post request to trigger notification in the index file but I still see two cards posted at once and I want just one. Any idea what could be going wrong ?

Comment: Are those welcome messages or notification messages? I'd suggest to add breakpoint or log to see how many `sendActivity` calls and how many `installations` returned. Or, if you meet this issue when F5 locally, try 1)delete file `.notification.localstore.json`. 2)re-launch your app. 3)send any message to the bot. 4)try notification again.

Comment: So, I commented out the install part already, removed support for notification. 

You see this function

  bot.adapter.process(req, res, async(context) => {
    /// log context.activity.text ...
    await botActivityHandler.run(context);
  });
});

is being called twice is the issue. I logged context and saw it is hitting and printing twice and I see two cards

Comment: For the twice calls, the detailed body data should be different. E.g., `type`, `id`, or any other field. It seems a Teams issue but you can de-dup by certain field from your code.